# Trapezoid as page background in css3?

Tags: css, background

i'm trying to create this in css3:
[trapezoid and trianlge backgorund](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhD1n.png)

I can make classic triangles as a css3 background:

```
body {
background-image: linear-gradient(319deg, black 16px, transparent 17px), linear-gradient(39deg, black 16px, transparent 17px);
background-size: 54px 23px;
background-repeat: repeat;}
```

but i can't achieve the same result as in the picture ([trapezoid and trianlge backgorund](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DhD1n.png)), anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

so here is my solution:

```css
html, 
body {
   width: 100%;
  height:100%;
  min-height:100%;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
body {
background: #fff;
background:
linear-gradient(150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 105px) calc(50% + 46px),
linear-gradient(-150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 105px) calc(50% + 46px),

linear-gradient(29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px),
linear-gradient(-29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px),

linear-gradient(150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 105px) calc(50% + 46px + 411px),
linear-gradient(-150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 105px) calc(50% + 46px + 411px),

linear-gradient(29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px + 411px),
linear-gradient(-29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px + 411px),


linear-gradient(150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 105px - 270px) calc(50% + 46px + 558px),
linear-gradient(-150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 105px - 270px) calc(50% + 46px + 558px),

linear-gradient(29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 1px - 270px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px + 558px),
linear-gradient(-29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 1px - 270px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px + 558px),

linear-gradient(150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 105px - 270px) calc(50% + 46px + 558px + 411px),
linear-gradient(-150.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 105px - 270px) calc(50% + 46px + 558px + 411px),

linear-gradient(29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 1px - 270px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px + 558px + 411px),
linear-gradient(-29.5deg, white 4.2%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 1px - 270px) calc(50% + 59px + 46px + 558px + 411px),

  
  
  linear-gradient(111deg, rgb( 217,217,214) 20.9%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 19px - 281px),
  linear-gradient(-111deg,  rgb( 217,217,214) 20.9%, transparent 0%) calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% + 19px - 281px),

 linear-gradient(111deg, transparent 79.1%,  rgb( 217,217,214) 79.1%)  calc(50% + 1px) calc(50% - 14px - 281px),
  linear-gradient(-111deg, transparent 79.1%,  rgb( 217,217,214) 79.1%) calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% - 14px - 281px),
  
    linear-gradient(111deg, rgb( 217,217,214) 20.9%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 271px) calc(50% + 16px + 281px),
  linear-gradient(-111deg,  rgb( 217,217,214) 20.9%, transparent 0%) calc(50% - 269px) calc(50% + 16px + 281px),
  
   linear-gradient(111deg, transparent 79.1%,  rgb( 217,217,214) 79.1%)  calc(50% - 269px) calc(50% - 16px + 281px),
  linear-gradient(-111deg, transparent 79.1%,  rgb( 217,217,214) 79.1%)  calc(50% - 271px) calc(50% - 16px + 281px),
white;
background-size: 540px 1118px;

}
```